# Unable to find control within listview or assign value to navigate url property

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hope all is well with everyone today.

I have run into a little problem that I am struggling with, I'm sure it's probably something simple but the longer I stare at it the less sense it seems to make.

I have a details view, which has in it a listview. The listview displays images. I have wrapped  around the images an asp:hyperlink but an unable to set the navigateUrl from the code behind, which I am trying to do from the listviews databound event. For some reason the hyperlink control is proving difficult to find.

my .aspx:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="productDetails" OnDataBound="productDetails_DataBound" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false">
    <Fields>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 id="prodNamelbl" runat="server" class="text-center"><%# Eval("ProductName") %></h2>
                    <asp:Image ID="prodMainImage" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' />
                </div>

                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <asp:ListView ID="listOtherImages" OnDataBound="listOtherImages_DataBound" OnPagePropertiesChanging="listOtherImages_PagePropertiesChanging" runat="server">
                             <LayoutTemplate>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></div>
                        </div>
                       <asp:DataPager runat="server" PagedControlID="listOtherImages"  ID="imgListDataPager"
                            PageSize="3">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="true"

                        ShowNextPageButton="false" />

                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />

                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton = "false" />
                            </Fields>

                        </asp:DataPager>

                    </LayoutTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>



                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="imgLink" runat="server" >
                                        <asp:Image ID="supImage" Height="80px" Width="80px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" AlternateText='<%# Eval("ImgId") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' runat="server" />
                                    </asp:HyperLink>

                                    </div>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

my code behind:

```
protected void listOtherImages_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView imgs = (ListView)productDetails.FindControl("listOtherImages");
    foreach (ListViewItem item in imgs.Items)
    {
        try
        {
            // find controls
            Image prodImage = (Image)item.FindControl("supImg");
            HyperLink picLink = (HyperLink)item.FindControl("imgLink");
            // assign value to NavigateUrl
            picLink.NavigateUrl = "~/ProductCatalogue/prodImage.aspx?ImageId=" + prodImage.AlternateText;

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error finding controls: " + err.Data + "<br />" + err.Message + "<br />" + err.InnerException;
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you in advanced to anyone who can help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are unnecessarily looping through the list view items on the databound event. Change the funtion as below and check.

```
protected void listOtherImages_DataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem )
    {
        try
        {
            // find controls
            Image prodImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("supImg");
            HyperLink picLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("imgLink");
            // assign value to NavigateUrl
            picLink.NavigateUrl = "~/ProductCatalogue/prodImage.aspx?ImageId=" + prodImage.AlternateText;

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error finding controls: " + err.Data + "<br />" + err.Message + "<br />" + err.InnerException;
        }


    }
}
```

Also I noticed that in the databound event you are just assigning the navigateURL of the hyperlink. This you can directly do in the ASPX as below

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="imgLink" runat="server" 
 NavigateUrl='<%# "~/ProductCatalogue/prodImage.aspx?ImageId=" + Eval("ImgId") %>' 
 Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive") %>'>
```

Comment: Did you change the parameter of the event handler to ListViewItemEventArgs e. Because in your implementation it is just EventArgs e

Comment: I have now but when I run the page I cannot click the link but I am unsure of why.

Comment: check the href generated for the link. Also debug and check what URL is assgned to hyperlink. You can check doing this directly on aspx as I suggested in the answer

Comment: thankyou @Kiran Hedge you have helped me enormously, thank you so much ;)